# Excel 2-step lookup; non-unique ID followed by range

Tags: excel

Lookup array has column A containing non-unique ID, column B containing min. age, column C containing max. age. It's the combination of these 3 columns that make the lookup unique (I suppose technically it could be just A and B or A and C). Column D contains the value I need to obtain.

In my other table, I have the non-unique ID that would match column A, and an age value. I need to be able to lookup first based on the ID and then to find which row specifically that the age value falls in the range of.

How do I achieve this?

ie. lookup range

ID101 | 18 | 30 | 10.5

ID101 | 31 | 50 | 15.0

for a lookup of ID101 and age 40, I need 15.0 returned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what pnuts posted, I appended the ID and min. age as the lookup ID and used non-exact matching VLOOKUP. Granted this is assuming that my data has no error such that I am looking up for things past the maximum age - easily fixed by another check.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are 99% of the way there with "It's the combination of these 3 columns that make the lookup unique" - the normal way to deal with such issues (of which there are LOTS on SO) is to concatenate your three columns (in a helper column) for a lookup table - or better still two, if sufficient.

It then requires the search term also be concatenate but that can be achieved "on the fly", for example =VLOOKUP("A"&"B",array,offset,0).

Search SO and there will be MANY examples.